# Sample Java Program to Translate Sample Text using Microsoft Azure Text Translator API

Tags: java, azure

I am trying to translate sample text from one language to another language using Microsoft Azure Text Translator API through Java Program.

Please, provide me steps to create appId, Secret key for Microsoft Azure Text Translator API and sample Java program to convert sample text from one language to another language.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help in order to ask a well received question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, I think you want to use [`Microsoft Translator - Text Translation`](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/microsofttranslator) from Microsoft DataMarket in Java program, but seems to not know how to get started with it.

First of all, you need to register an application via https://datamarket.azure.com/developer/applications/register to get the `client_id` & `client_secret` after login Microsoft DataMarket

[image]

Then, please refer to the documents below to know how to get `access_token` & translate API.

1. Obtaining an Access Token, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx
2. Using the HTTP Interface, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512387.aspx
3. Translator Language Codes, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh456380.aspx

As reference, here is my sample code with Java libraries [`apache commons-io`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi) & [`fastjson`](https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson).

```
package sample;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON;

public class TextTranslatorTest {

    public static String getAccessToken(String charset, String clientId, String clientSecret, String scope,
            String grantType) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        String url = "https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13";
        String paramsTemplate = "client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&scope=%s&grant_type=%s";
        String params = String.format(paramsTemplate, URLEncoder.encode(clientId, charset),
                URLEncoder.encode(clientSecret, charset), scope, grantType);
        System.out.println(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=" + charset);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        IOUtils.write(params, conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");;
        String resp = IOUtils.toString(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(resp);
        String accessToken = JSON.parseObject(resp).getString("access_token");
        return accessToken;
    }

    public static String translate(String charset, String accessToken, String text, String from, String to) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        String url = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?text=" + URLEncoder.encode(text, charset) + "&from=" + from + "&to=" + to;
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + accessToken);
        String resp = IOUtils.toString(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
        return resp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        String charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name();
        String clientId = "peter-translator-test";
        String clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        String scope = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com";
        String grantType = "client_credentials";
        String accessToken = getAccessToken(charset, clientId, clientSecret, scope, grantType);
        System.out.println(accessToken);
        String text = "happy";
        String from = "en";
        String to = "de";
        String resp = translate(charset, accessToken, text, from, to);
        System.out.println(resp);
    }
}
```

Notice, according to the page https://translatorbusiness.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1078534-microsoft-translator-on-azure, you just use the answer above before April 30, 2017. Then, you need to follow the new document http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html to use Text Translator API on Azure. But the new service of Text Translator on Azure seems to be not ready via my testing. So I just list the simple steps below as reference.

1. Get Azure access token, please refer to http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/oauth-token.html. To get `<your-key>`, you can refer to the steps 12 of the new document to `Go to the Keys option and copy your subscription key to access the service`.

   // Pass key using header
   curl --header 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ' --data "" 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken'
   // Pass key using query string parameter
   curl --data "" 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken?Subscription-Key='
2. To call the `/Translate` HTTP interface, please refer to http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html#!/default/get_Translate.