# Migrating to Azure Translation API

Tags: android, api, azure, translation

I need some help regarding Migrating my existing Android app to Azure Translation APi (text to text). There is C# sample code available but there is no example code or instructions for Java or Android.

Regards,
Nabeel.

Comment: Questions asking for tutorials/samples/offsite reference material are off-topic for StackOverflow. Also, this is a wide-open, broad question. Consider editing your question to be specific to the issue(s) you're running into. What have you tried? Which API calls are you trying to make? Etc.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me about Stackoverflow rules for asking question. I will ask if i face any issue with my code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to refer to the sample code for Azure Translation API in Java. As reference, there was an existing SO thread [Sample Java Program to Translate Sample Text using Microsoft Azure Text Translator API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41634375/sample-java-program-to-translate-sample-text-using-microsoft-azure-text-translat) which had the Java sample code may be helpful for you. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much @Peter Pan. I will surely let you know if i need to ask further question regarding this issue.